# how do I measure similarity with canonical correlation analysis?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, canonical-correlation

With canonical correlation analysis for two random vectors $X$ and $Y$, we do SVD on

$$(C_XX)^{-1/2} C_XY C_{YY}^{-1/2}$$

to get $U$ and $V$ from the singular vector decomposition, and then define the projection $A = C_{XX}^{-1/2} U$ and $B = C_{YY}^{-1/2} V$. We can now project the random vectors $X$ and $Y$ using $A$ and $B$ to say $X_p$ and $Y_p$ respectively.

My question is, if I wanted to measure the similarity between $X_p$ and $Y_p$ for a specific sample $x_p$ and $y_p$ -- would I use dot product between the two, cosine similarity, or something else? Also, what would be the most theoretically-motivated way to do that?

Comment: CCA itself is not a cluster analysis nor a classification for data points. It is a multivariate correlation / dimensionality reduction technique for variables. Therefore it does not impose a strict measure of similarity for you to use. Still, it might "whisper" Mahalanobis distance on your ear. The reason is that CCA is tied theoretically with MANOVA, and with linear discriminant analysis - the analyses making notion of Mahalanobis distance. (If you are interested, please seach this site for threads with words `canonical correlation manova lda`.)

Comment: If you want to disragard the factor of covariation, Euclidean distance is the natural choice.